# Remove everything from specific HTML string to specific string using sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, html-parsing

I have a html file with this in it:

```
<div id="date">Saturday 04.08.18<br><div id="time">23<img src="media/images/sec.gif">59</div></div>
```

and i want to delete this complete element out of the html file but the values are changing each minute (because it is the time)

i had tried this command edited from another guy here but it is not working.

```
sed -z -r -i 's#<div id="date">[^<]*</div></div>\n?##g' 1.htm
```

i think this may not work because there starts another html element in the element?

Comment: `sed -r -e 's#<div id="date">.*</div></div>\n?##g' 1.htm` ?

Comment: yes! Thank you!

Comment: ok I'll make it as answer, feel free to accept it

Comment: The canonical answer is usually use a different tool to manipulate XML/HTML/SGML/etc.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution will be the following:

```
sed -r -e 's#<div id="date">.*</div></div>\n?##g' 1.htm
```

what it does is basically substitute with empty string the lines containing `div` tag with `date` id, followed by, greater than zero (or equal to) characters, ending with two closing div tags, plus a new line char